# Multiple inline textOutputs

Tags: r, shiny, output

I'm fairly new to R and I have a shiny app that displays a plot that updates with user input much like the movie explorer here:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html

I am able to output the regression line equation, but all elements are on different lines, rather than a single line like an equation would be seen.  I have attached a screenshot of what it looks like now on the shiny app.

[Screenshot of Current App Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfi0C.png)

On the UI I have:

```
wellPanel(
         span(h4("Linear Regression Line: "), h5(textOutput("slope"), "x +", textOutput("intercept")))
       )
```

And on the Server I have:

```
output$slope <- renderText({coefficients(lm(`var1` ~ `var2`, data=filteredData()))[2]})
output$intercept <- renderText({coefficients(lm(`var1` ~ `var2`, data=filteredData()))[1]})
```

Any ideas on how to get those equation elements on the same line?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by specifying inline = TRUE within each of the textOutputs.  My UI code is reposted below as the server code is unchanged.

```
wellPanel(
     span(h4("Linear Regression Line: "), h5(textOutput("slope", inline = TRUE), "x +", textOutput("intercept", inline = TRUE)))
   )
```